# How to password protect a Truecrypt volume using a Diffie Hellman public key exchange?

Tags: truecrypt, diffie-hellman

I want to send a Truecrypt volume through email. Of course, I need to password protect it, and the recipient needs to know the password too. A Diffie-Hellman public key exchange would seem to be the solution. What is the easiest and safest way of doing this? Specific instructions would help.

Comment: Please don't forget Truecrypt is NOT secure anymore since 5/2014 (source: http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/ ).

Comment: Yes, I have followed the story on that. In my judgment, Truecrypt is as safe today as it was six months ago. So far nothing amiss has been found in the code and there is not one single known instance of it having been cracked, weak passwords excepted. Either the anonymous developers had some crazy bust up, or it closed because US governmental agencies attempted to force the developers to include a backdoor in the next version.

Comment: indeed, thats one of the seculations at the office here, but since there isn't a real expert here, we use Bitlocker on our private PC's, but because its more microsoft, we're still in doubt if we should use the warning given and fully use botlocker, because MS is known for NSA backdoors (but also for attempting to resist it, which is harden then people think in common media).

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the person you are sending the volume to Bob, since that is traditional. Then:

1. You choose a very large - at least 300 digits long - prime number *p*, and a small number *g* and send them to Bob (the person you are sending the Truecrypt volume to).
2. You pick a large (at least 100 digits) secret number *a*.
3. Bob picks a large (at least 100 digits) secret number *b*.
4. You calculate the value of *g^a mod p* and send it to Bob. Call this
   *C*.
5. Bob calculates *g^b mod p* and sends it to you. Call this *D*.
6. You calculate *D^a mod p*. This gives you a secret number *S*.
7. Bob calculates *C^b mod p*. This gives him *S* as well.

Now you an Bob both know *S*. Eve, who has listened to the whole conversation, knows the values of *p*, *g*, *C*, and *D* but she cannot calculate the value of *S* because she does not know the values of *a* or *b* - those were secret and never went over the insecure communication channel.

Note however that **this is not enough to solve your problem**. You are still vulnerable to a Man-In-The-Middle attack. If Eve can impersonate Bob and trick you into doing the above with her instead of him, then she gets to pick *b* and so she can work our *S*. So you need to add some authentication so you are sure that it's really Bob you are talking to.

Comment: Thanks for that. But as a non-specialist I need something which has already been made (e.g. a html JavaScript doc) which the other party and I can use to generate the password for the Truecrypt Volume. It’s completely beyond me to write the program myself! What do you recommend from what is already out there on the web? And preferably something simple and free!

Comment: Suggest you go back and state the problem more accurately then. You asked how to do a Diffie-Hellman; there isn't going to be an answer to that that doesn't involve Mathematics. Instead try something like "I need to securely exchange a password. This is my threat model: <<details of who/what you are protecting the data from>>"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use some form of secure email: S/MIME or PGP. Both have advantage and disadvantage that are out of scope but they both will allow you to protect the password (you can protect the TC file as well but it's unnecessary).

You *could* perform a [DH key agreement exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) over email, mind you:

***I do not recommend you follow these steps: using a standard mail security package will be both simpler and more secure***

Here is how you'd do it, however:

- Send a first message where you agree on the values of P and G (there are plenty of libraries that can help you do that or you could even pick an existing combination)
- Each pick your secret integer (large enough) a and b
- Each perform (A=G^a mod P) and (B=G^b mod P) and exchange A and B
- Each perform (s=b^a mod P) and (s=b^a mod P) to obtain a shared secret s
- use s as password for your TC file.

Please note, however, that you need to use values of reasonable size for security (P must be about that 1024 bits at least, for instance) so you'll have to use big number arithmetic to manipulate them and you will need to check that they do not belong to a special class of weak values (see the answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/diffie-hellman-choosing-wrong-generator-g-parameter-and-its-implications-of-p) which describe the issue).

Because of that, picking P and G can be tricky and complex. I would recommend you use OpenSSL to do it for you in the following way:

```
openssl dhparam 1024 -text
```

This will generate a 1024  long P using the default generator G=2 and display it in a (somewhat) readable format.

Comment: Thanks for that. But as a non-specialist I need something which has already been made (e.g. a html JavaScript doc) which the other party and I can use to generate the password for the Truecrypt Volume. It’s completely beyond me to write the program myself! What do you recommend from what is already out there on the web? And preferably something simple and free.

Comment: Please, read the first paragraph. That is the one aimed at non-specialists.